# Show row after pressing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

[image: Rows and 'Load More']

I want to show Row #1 on default and then when you press the "load more" button, load another row each time. I already have the content in the rows (no need for AJAX) but I just want to be able to show it when the button's pressed.

Comment: What's the question? Do you have any piece of code?

Comment: It's three divs with images inside each one. I just need help with the Javascript.

Comment: [so] is for developers. Unless you've already written some code you need help with, and are willing to show said code, you're probably in the wrong place.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris I think if you're going to make that comment you need to at least say where it would be more appropriate for them to ask this question.

Comment: Fair enough! :) [TutsPlus - Learn jQuery](http://learnjquery.tutsplus.com/)

Answer (score 2):

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pE3L/) example.

The JavaScript part, with jQuery:

```
$('#loadmore').click(function(){
     $('tr.hide').first().removeClass('hide').addClass('show'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: none;` by default on all rows (except row #1).

Then on each click, use `.show()` on the given row or :

```
$('BUTTON_SELECTOR').click(function(){
    $('ROWS_CONTAINER_SELECTOR:hidden:first').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the data then you can simply set the container div to `overflow: hidden` and resize it to display an extra row with each click.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $("#container").css("height","+=150");
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I'm trying to achieve but am missing the Javascript part.

Comment: Good solution I think. Nice and simple. If you wanted to animate the showing of the new row this is definitely the way to go, otherwise I think darma's solution is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution assumes the padding, margin, and height of each row will remain constant.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris That's why I think Darma's answer would be more appropriate. He could obviously take that into account, but then the solution actually becomes worse unless he needs to animate revealing the next row by expanding the container height.

Comment: I think it's fair to assume the dimensions are known beforehand if the content is already hard-coded (no ajax), however I also like darma's solution

Comment: @CosminPascu It's definitely *not* safe to assume that, because in all likelihood, the styling *will* change, and the above JavaScript will need to be adjusted to compensate for it. JavaScript shouldn't be a function of your stylesheet, nor visa-versa.